# Using apt search to find a string regardless of positioning

Tags: ubuntu, apt, regular-expression

Here is the pseudo code for what I would like to achieve:
`sudo apt search *something*`
`E: Regex compilation error` (error message for trying)

The idea is to search for the string regardless of the positioning. I have come across `^something` for matching the start of a string, and `something$` for matching the end of a string but not a search that searches for it all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a moot question, I believe `*` isnt required as `apt search` already searches everywhere for the occurring string.